# Using sortedList to count words in a List

Tags: c#, sortedlist

For my homework, I have to use a SortedList to count words in a List with SortedList taking each entry and sorting it in alphabetical order before inserting. When it comes to display the data to the user, the data displayed should be displayed with sorting according to value instead of key.

Below is my attempt at this but I am getting 3 errors and I don't know how to resolve it. I am not allowed to use LINQ for this.

```
List<string> words = new List<string>(); <--- Already populated
```

This is my code of this implementation and I get 3 errors:

```
            SortedList<string, int> d = new SortedList<string, int>();
            bool InsideOfList = false;

foreach (string word in words)
{
    InsideOfList = false;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyvalPair in d)
    {

        if (keyvalPair.Key == word)
        {
            keyvalPair.Value += 1;
            InsideOfList = true;
        }

    }
    if (InsideOfList == false)
    {
        d.Add(word,1);
    }
}
//Now instead of sorting by key I want to sort by value instead

SortedList<int, string> tempSortList = new SortedList<int, string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyvalPair in d)
{
//trying to swap the value of previous SortedList with the Key of the new SortedList
    tempSortList.Add(keyvalPair.Value, keyvalPair.Key);

}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\t{1}", tempSortList.GetKey(i), tempSortList.GetByIndex(i));

}
```

Here are my errors:

```
Property or indexer 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

'System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<int,string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetKey'

'System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<int,string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetByIndex'
```

Comment: From where you copied this code?,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez It is my own code

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I found out the GetKey() method from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You are confusing two things. One is SortedList() and other is SortedList<TKey, TValue>(). You are using second one here. And that doesn't contain GetKey and GetKeyList methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things here. One is SortedList() and other is SortedList().

GetKey and GetKeyList are not present in SortedList(). You can use this instead of GetKey

```
tempSortList.ElementAt(index); // This will return you a KeyValuePair.
```

And for the first error you cannot assign value keyvalPair.Value has only getter. So you cannot set its value by doing += 1.

This is not quite good. Needs some improvement but it will work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++)
{
    if (d.ElementAt(i).Key == word)
    {
        d.Values[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++)
{
    if (d.ElementAt(i).Key == word)
    {
        var val = d.ElementAt(i).Value + 1;
        d.RemoveAt(i);
        d.Add(word, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: what can I do to set its value? I am really out of options here

Answer (score -1):

Please modify this line and check if it works. it should.

```
Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\t{1}", tempSortList.GetKey(i), tempSortList.GetByIndex(i));
```

to

```
var key = tempSortedList.Keys[i];
var value = tempSortedList.Values[i];
Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\t{1}", key, value);
```

Comment: Why the downVote? Anyway this line will do the job for value update

d[keyvalPair.Key] += 1; //or any value you need